# Why isn't my data inserted into the DB table?

Tags: php, mysql

I don't see the problem. None of my data will insert into the registration database. Please check the INSERT INTO part. I'm a beginner at coding so I don't know alot of this stuff. Please help me.

```
<?php 

**my info is here**

//Connect to database 

mysql_connect ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error()); 
?> 


<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
$username = $_POST[user]; 
$password = $_POST[pass]; 

// lets check to see if the username already exists 

$checkuser = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM register WHERE username='$username'");  

$username_exist = mysql_num_rows($checkuser); 

 if($username_exist > 0){ 
echo "I'm sorry but the username you specified has already been taken.Please pick      another one."; 
unset($username); 
exit(); 
}  

// lf no errors present with the username 
// use a query to insert the data into the database. 

$query = ("INSERT INTO register (username, password) 
VALUES ('$username', '$password')"); 
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_close($query); 


} 


?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You’re storing raw passwords in the database and not escaping your input or using parametrized queries. This is already not a good start. You should fix that first by using PDO instead!

Comment: You really shouldn't be using any `mysql_*` functions, instead use MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: For one thing, `$username = $_POST[user];` should be `$username = $_POST['user'];` and `$password = $_POST[pass];` should be `$password = $_POST['pass'];`. You left out the apostrophes. May just be the "why". Change those and see what that gives.

Comment: @Fred: Bad, but still “valid”.

Comment: @Fred: Bare words are converted to strings by default with a notice. It’s PHP, what can ya do.

Comment: You should test `isset($_POST['user'])` and `isset($_POST['pass'])`

Comment: to explain that, php will convert any bare words to strings if it otherwise doesn't understand them. this is a horrible "feature", but it's there. not just in php either, i believe perl used to do it and maybe still does. (edit: oops minitech beat me)

Comment: `mysql_close($query)` should be `mysql_close()`, by the way.

Comment: @minitech thanks, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks to you too `sgroves`. I "learned" something new.

Comment: @user2521853 check the error_log file and it should tell  you what the problem is.

Comment: Could it be there's **password** missing in `$checkuser = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM register WHERE username='$username'");`? he's only selecting `WHERE username=....`.

Comment: @Fred nope he only wants to check to make sure there are no dupes for the username. **Looks** like he's doing a registration form.

Comment: @Fred that's OK why would he want to add password if he only needs to know if the username exists there ?

Comment: @Pjack 10-4. I'll just **slowly back away** from this one. I'll let you **pros** have a go at it ;-)

Comment: @Prix I don't know, I thought that might've been it.

Comment: LOL even with the comment above the query pointing to it ? :P

Comment: Two words for you: unique constraint

Comment: @Prix It would surely have helped, had the OP posted the errors **"right off the bat"** and after you asked for them.

Comment: @user2521853 your code works just fine, can you post the form you're using ? I assume the submit may not be set at your form causing your php to skip your `IF` if you place an echo by the end of your code you will see it reaches it without error and one inside your first `IF` will never go into.

Comment: @Prix I just helped this guy out earlier, as so others tried. Ended up being a typo in the **form** itself which the OP didn't bother posting. *Grrr* **Gnashing teeth**.

Comment: @Prix (Damn's the word) You could post the **form** that "you" made for it and post it as an "answer" lol. You "did" make a form, *right*? *grin*

Comment: Ya kinda gotta wonder, where the OP is in all of this(?). * groan *

Comment: Ripe for SQL injection, but everyone has already pointed that out...why don't you hand over the wild URL and we can take turns picking it apart.

Comment: I guess the presence depends on the urgency of it

Comment: @Prix True. Maybe he's gone **"back to the 'ol drawing board"**, *as it were*. (?)

Answer (score 0):

The commenters are correct that you should be using mysqli or PDO, but try this out to see if it solves your issue:

```
if(isset($_POST)){ 
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']); 
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']); 

    // lets check to see if the username already exists 

    $checkuser = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM register WHERE username='$username'");  

    $username_exist = mysql_num_rows($checkuser); 

    if($username_exist > 0){ 
        echo "I'm sorry but the username you specified has already been taken. Please pick another one."; 
        unset($username); 
        exit(); 
    }  

    // if no errors present with the username 
    // use a query to insert the data into the database. 

    $query = ("INSERT INTO register (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')"); 
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_close(); 
} else {
    echo "No form submission detected.";
}
```

If you're still having issues, I'd like to see the form you're submitting to this page as well as the table layout for ***register***.